# How to always put long expression in next line, when defining single-expression function?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

Kotlin allows to define a single-line expression function like this:

```
fun double(x: Int) = x * 2
```

It's very convenient. Now if we have more complicated expression:

```
fun someMoreComplicatedMethod(x: Int): Double = (x * 2) / (someMoreComplicatedMethod(x - 1) + 10)
```

As you can see, it's easy to exceed the line width. So we can move expression into next line.

```
fun someMoreComplicatedMethod(x: Int): Double 
        = (x * 2) / (someMoreComplicatedMethod(x - 1) + 10)
```

Unfortunately, when I format the code with Android Studio the expression returns to its original place. Question is, how to set code style in Android Studio in order to move mentioned expression into next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set using

> Code Style -> Kotlin -> Expression body functions - > wrap if too long
>   or wrap always

The only problem is that it will wrap the line but if you format it manually by moving the = to a new line it won't move it back to the function declaration line

Comment: Actually `=` stays the same, but expression moves to next line. But of course it's acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: No, it returns into first line. I'm using Android Studio 3.2 Preview.